# Common database in LAN

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, client-server, lan

I'm making system like client-server. There's two possibilities: to log in as user or admin. On one of the machines, e.g. superadmin's machine is storing main database. There's option to log in as administrator from any machine and to get datas from this main database.

But I've problem - what if this machine'll be broke? This db should be available all the time, but putting the db with the same datas on each machine it doesn't make sense.
I think about chosing proportional amounts of machines that will be store copies of main database: e.g. 2 on 10 computers in LAN.

Is there any better idea? Or better proportions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server supports both [failover clustering](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/articles/clustering/clustering_intro_p1.aspx) which it sounds like you want here and [replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198.aspx)  which you could also use to maintain multiple instances.

in a failover cluster if one instance goes down the clients won't notice it, in a replication scenario you have multiple sql servers, each client is tied to one sql server, if one goes down then all the clients using that server will have a problem (of course, you *could* go ahead and custom make your own failover implementation on top of replicated sql servers, but I would highly recommend you to use the technology provided by Microsoft instead)

Answer (score 1):

This machine is commonly called server, made of server HW (more reliable and performant, and of course expensive) and certainly not “superadmin's machine”.

There are [ways](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replication_%28computer_science%29) to have more than one server, but I think this would just add unnecessary complexity to your application.

Comment: Yes, I know that's serwer, but I want to emphasize importance of this one machine among many administrators. This datas are important so I'm not sure if this is "unnecessary complexity"...maybe any other approach?

Comment: Saint, if this is valuable data, I recommend RAID to guard against hard disks crashing.

Comment: I haven't that option because the application is designed for multiple networks to which I have no physical access.